# How to copy a value from a certain pattern in R?

Tags: r

I have a data file, each row may have different format, but the certain pattern `"\\- .*\\| PR"`, the data set is kind as following:

```
 |- 7 | PR - Easy to post position and search resumes | Improvement - searching of resumes
 [ 1387028] | Recommend - 9 | PR - As a recruiter I find a lot qualified resumes for jobs that I am working on. 
 |- 10 | PR - its easy to use and good candidiates
```

I want to have a record of the number in this pattern, or the data I offered, I need a record of 7, 9,10. I have no idea about how to do it, is there someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
as.integer(sub('.*- ([0-9]+) \\| PR.*', '\\1', yourvector))
```